# Do I need a lintel? Will I need to prop wall/roof?

Tags: doors, windows, load-bearing

I'd like to replace my garage window with french doors as I want to put an office/workshop in there and there's currently no side access. My garage is single skin brick, built in the 60s and there is no lintel above the window, just a soldier course. I was under the impression that I should put a lintel in there when I swap the window for a door however the door fitter I got round to have a look said I didn't need one as there's no more brickwork above the soldiers.

My question(s): 1) is this correct, or should I put in a lintel? 2) If I do need to put in a lintel, will I need to prop up the wall/roof or can I get away with just taking out the soldier course and quickly popping in a lintel? I imagine this will depend on if the wall is load bearing which is why I've attached a photo of the roof.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

---

EDIT: Just to clarify: the current window is 1800mm wide and the french doors that will replace it will be the same width. The only brick removal required will be from the bottom of the window opening to the ground - none at the sides.

I've added an extra photo showing a close up of what is above the window - hopefully this helps.

Thank you for all your responses so far!

[image: garage roof structure and window]

[image]

Comment: If the existing window is as wide as the french door and is placed right below the roof (with one course of brick), then you don't need lintel, as the loading on the edge beam remains the same for both cases. If not, I suggest checking the strength of the edge beam to span the full opening without excessive deflection, which will cause problem on the door.

Comment: Yes it’s a load bearing wall above the existing window and yes you’ll need to add a header after you remove the soldier course above the existing windows.

Comment: Btw, your “door fitter” is nuts. There is no “more masonry above the existing masonry lintel”. Also, that lintel will weigh about 1,600 lbs. when it comes down. (100 lbs. per linear foot X 16’ = 1600 lbs. AND that wood plate resting on top of the lintel is probably bolted to the lintel and will probably drag the roof down when it comes down. Make sure your contractor has insurance.

Comment: Could you add a pic with a straight-on view of the top half pf the window and whatever is above it? I can't really make out for sure if that edge of the roof has some sort of real horizontal support (since the soldier course can't be structural and the window frame itself should not be supporting any load from the roof).

Comment: Your latest update indicates you are replacing a door that has the same width as the existing window, so structurally speaking, you are essentially replace something with the same without changing the load path. Note neither the window nor the bricks below carry any roof load. So your contractor was correct, you don't need a lintel, but please do provide adequate shoring to the roof throughout the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

The sketch below is to clarify my previous comments. For the condition as shown to the left, the edge beam (in conjunction with the masonry bond beam below) was designed to support the roof without depressing the window/door frame below, so you can replace the existing window/door without needing a lintel.

For the figure on the right, the roof could either be supported by the edge beam as indicated above or by the bearing wall below (with a short masonry bond beam over the opening), so you need to figure out which support system the current wall falls into. You may, or may not require a lintel, depending on the strength of the edge beam and the configuration of the masonry bond beam (full or partial over the opening), which is better handled by an engineer.

Yes, for either case you would need to provide shoring to support the roof for safety. I'll remove and replace the bricks on top of the opening if it is not a full span bond beam.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don’t think you understand the structural system of the existing wall / window system. First, neither of your drawings are correct. Your drawing on the left shows a door and windows without showing (nor labeling) the masonry lintel, which carries the vertical load. I think you’re implying the “edge beam” (actually it’s a rim joist) is acting as a header… it’s not. Second, your new drawing shows a single door, when the op says “french doors”. (Probably 2 doors) And again you’re suggesting the “edge beam” is carrying the vertical beam. Even if it

Comment: Even if it is a single door, the “edge beam “ will not act as a header, because the roof joists extend beyond the masonry lintel. Plz add the term “masonry lintel “ in the existing condition drawing as bd “header” in the new proposed French door(s) drawing.

Comment: @LeeSam Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Actually, “bond beam” implies something different than “lintel”.

Comment: @LeeSam That's correct. The OP stated that there is no lintel above the window, so the possibility is a bond beam or masonry arch/lintel over the window. As the brick looks like the CMU blocks, thus bond beam makes better sense. Actually, if this is the case, he shall consider rebuilding the bond beam to cover the new opening rather than use a lintel. But from his photo, I think the first case is more likely.

Comment: He calls it a “soldier course”, which is merely describing the orientation of the units. One of our jobs is to correct the op and get the terms correct.  Soldier course is a description of the orientation of the masonry units. It’s a lintel not a bond beam as you have labeled it on your drawing.

Comment: @LeeSam I appreciate your timely catch of my omission, I don't think there is a need to further discuss bond beam vs lintel (a beam element under the brick). If you feel the need, you can communicate directly with the OP.